# Java Applet Windows-MY keystore PrivateKey getEncoded is null

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate, x509certificate

According to my understanding of [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html) there should be possbile to access Microsoft Windows KeyStore by service `"Windows-MY"`.

When I load PrivateKey from keyStore I get `null` for privateKey.getEncoded().

How can I properly access PrivateKey from Windows keystore?

Trying to access it with:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("myKeyAlias", null);
System.out.println("privateKey:" + privateKey));
System.out.println("getEncoded:" + privateKey.getEncoded());
```

Output I'm getting:

```
privateKey:RSAPrivateKey [size=2048 bits, type=Exchange, container=myKeyAlias]
getEncoded:null
```

Using JRE 1.8 and tested with Win7 and 8.1

Comment: Eh? It's a bit of a stretch to assume that every computer on which your applet will ever run (a) is using Windows and (b) has a KeyStore entry called "myKeyAlias" (or whatever you're going to substitute there).

Comment: Yes, these are all prerequisites, and applet also knows about users key alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSCAPI does not seem to support private key export.

First of all the `Key.getEncoded()` javadoc specifies:

> Returns the key in its primary encoding format, or null if this key does not support encoding.

And if you look at the [source code of the Java crypto provider for MSCAPI](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/security/mscapi/Key.java/), the `getEncoded()` method actually returns `null` in all cases.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.